# This project is configured to use SSL. SSl warnings in the browser. Would you like to trust the IIS Express SSl certificate? Why do I see it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Why do I see this thing when I just started debugging ? Could Anybody tell me the reason?
Thanks)

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276414/how-to-fix-the-access-control-list-acl-structure-is-invalid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS Express SSL certificate is generated locally, so there is no trusted [root certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate) authority with it that the computer already knows about. The computer wants to check with you that it is OK to use that particular self-signed certificate.

The answer in this case is "Yes."