Visual Studio WSL, failed exporting certificate
I was running ASP NET on WSL using Visual Studio without issues. Now after some reinstalls, I getting an error with certificates. All the other like http, https, IIS are working fine. However I would need to have WSL available as well. Does anybody know how to make it work and fix this certificate issue?
I think I have tried already all the solutions available on the Internet. I have tried resetting Windows, installing WSL from the scratch with different Linux distributions. Removing existing localhost certificates from Certificate manager and also copying Windows certificates to my Linux.


GoodDay. Have you check this related question ?  There are many advice may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413183/visual-studio-2017-gives-adding-the-certificate-to-the-trusted-root-certificate

There is a good chance you've hit [Breaking change]: dev cert export no longer creates folder
The work-around is to run:
mkdir %appdata%\ASP.NET\Https


Can you elaborate on this? It does not work for me.

This fixed my issue. I see a .pfx file was created inside that folder for my project.
